# Why did the classes from libraries I imported is showing in red colour? I could build it perfectly and run works fine

Tags: android, module, shared-libraries, import-libraries

This is my app project. The classes looks fine

[image]

This is the libraries I imported as module. The classes are red in colour, why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new classes not added yet to the version control system.
Red indicates a file hasn't been added to staging - this means that when you run git commit, the red files will not be included. Calling git adds on the file will add to staging and turn it green.

Green indicates a completely new file is in staging and will be committed to the git repository when you run git commit

Comment: Noted, thanks. That means it does not bring harm to my project so no problem